# I'm having issues with nav responsive header is check or not

Tags: css, responsive, nav

My code have a checkbox and label in the header to check when is going to need to be responsive but the selector of being checked isn't working

Here's the thing: [Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smHzZ.png)

Anyone knows about what's going on?

```
 <div className="header-container">
  <nav>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <label htmlFor="check" className="checkbtn">
      <i>
        {" "}
        <HiOutlineViewList />{" "}
      </i>
    </label>
</div>
```

And the CSS code

```
@media (max-width: 730px) {
.checkbtn {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  margin-left: 0%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: $bg-header;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
ul li a:hover {
  color: $base-color-dark;
}
.right-container {
  display: none;
}
#check:checked ~ ul {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I can't work out what is required as the code doesn't seem to contain enough information - for example where is the ul element? Could you make it into a runnable snippet and describe what 'isn't working' means. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing that.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.